# China visa/work permit transfer

Tags: working-visas

If everything goes according to plan, I will transfer from working for a university to working for a local media organization in January. This is in Beijing. To transfer a work permit, the old employer has to give you a release letter, preferably ~30 days before it expires. My university is going to hold me to finishing my contract (no problem there), but does anyone have experience with transferring the visa at the end of a contract, and you didn't have to leave the country? Does the new employer's HR get you some kind of transitional visa?

I'd like to avoid having to make a totally new visa/work permit application. Right now I'm just making sure I have a good relationship with the relevant people at my university so they are more inclined to be helpful. Do you have any idea what the process would be likely to look like?

Thank you!